# Formatting data for survival analysis - time variable in long form data

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival

I'm new to survival analysis, and am unsure if I'm formatting my data correctly.
Using this dummy data:

```
id <- c(rep("1", 10), rep("2", 10), rep("3", 10), rep("4", 10), rep("5", 10))
age <- c((15:24), (35:44), (45:54), (55:64), (40:49))
event <- c(rep("0", 10), 
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
       0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
group <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
       "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a",
       "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "b", "b",
       "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c",
       "d", "d", "d", "d", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a")
df <- data.table(id, age, event, group)
df$tstart <- integer(0)
df$tstop <- df$age
df[, tstart := shift(tstop), by = id]
df$tstart <- ifelse(is.na(df$tstart), 14, df$tstart)

v1 <- survfit(Surv(age, event == 1) ~ group, data = df)
v2 <- survfit(Surv(tstart, tstop, event == 1) ~ group, data = df)
```

Within event, 1 = the event I'm focused on, 0 = event hasn't happened yet, and 2 = lost for another reason.

I'm looking at whether the age of "event" varies depending on what "group" you're in. I've seen code formatted as both:

```
coxph(Surv(age, event == 1) ~ group)
```

and

```
coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, event == 1) ~ group)
```

but I'm getting different results depending on what code I use, and the KM plots look completely different as well. I need the data as long form as I have time varying covariates.

Can anyone perhaps tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: This question might be better for cross validated because you have to take care of the statistical considerations before the coding issues.

Comment: Addressing the "what's correct" requires knowing what the question is. Is there any reason to think that censoring due to "not happened yet" and "lost for another reason" have different associations with group membership?